# Decompose incoming JSON to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have incoming json request in this format:

> { "id":"1", "fields":{"attr1":"value1", "attr2":"value2", ... "attrN":"valueN"}}

I need to decompose json string in my controller to this:

```
id: 1
attr1: value1
attr2: value2
...
attrN: valueN
```

How can I do this? I use Rails 4. Thanks

Comment: do you mean something like: `new_data = params[:fields].merge {id: params[:id].to_i}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanna add entire json hash to array, you can do something like this.

```
arr = Array.new

json_arr = { "id":"1", "fields":{"attr1":"value1", "attr2":"value2", ... "attrN":"valueN"}}

json_arr.each do |arr|
    temp_hash = Hash.new
    temp_hash = arr
    arr.push(arr)
end
```

I am not sure about your requirement.